# Unable to Install Zend-Server 6.1 on CentOS 6.5 wtih PHP 5.4 and nginx

Tags: nginx, php-5.4, zend-server

I'm getting "No package zend-server-nginx-php-5.4 available." after running yum install zend-server-nginx-php-5.4,  setting the repo accordingly (see below) and I have no other idea rather then updating php to solve this problem (something which may cause some problems on my app).

As mentioned on the question title i'm trying to install Zend-Server 6.1 on CentOS 6.5 wtih PHP 5.4 and nginx.

Any Ideas?

I have tried:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-zend-server-6-on-a-centos-6-4-vps
and
http://blog.petermcdonald.co.uk/2013/07/11/installing-zend-server-6-1-using-nginx-and-php-5-4/

Repo file is:

```
[Zend]
name=Zend Server 
baseurl=http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/6.1/rpm/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repos.zend.com/zend.key

[Zend_noarch]
name=Zend Server - noarch
baseurl=http://repos.zend.com/zend-server/6.1/rpm/noarch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://repos.zend.com/zend.key
```

Tried with this url and locally installing as well but it misses

"zend-server-php-5.4-common = 6.1.0-98"

and I'm not sure where to get that package. Help please!!

Comment: wow, weird, turned out I just had to clean packages cache before installing to ensure retrival of updates from the web. Just run:            yum clean all and then yum install zend-server-nginx-php-5.4

Answer (score 0):

Wow, weird, turned out I just had to clean packages cache before installing to ensure retrieval of updates from the web. Just run:

```
yum clean all
```

and then

```
yum install zend-server-nginx-php-5.4
```

installation runs fine.

Comment: Still, the ip address indicated to acess Zend Server shows a black screen. any ideas everyone?